# can anyone help wih castalia integration with omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I tried installing Castalia (version 3.0) but encountered the following error
               "./makemake: line 28: opp_makemake: command not found"
To rectify this error, I first installed castalia in the home directory and encountered the same above error.
             "root@roopali-HP-406-G1-MT:/home/roopali/Castalia-3.0# ./makemake

```
          ./makemake: line 28: opp_makemake: command not found"
```

To rectify this error, I tried installaing castalia in the omnet directory and encountered the same above error.
            "root@roopali-HP-406-G1-MT:/home/roopali/omnetpp-4.6/Castalia-3.0#       ./makemake

```
        ./makemake: line 28: opp_makemake: command not found"
```

Comment: Have you added `OMNeT++` bin directory into `PATH` system variable?

Comment: yes sir @JerzyD.

Comment: Could you write what do you see after typing `opp_makemake` in console?

Comment: opp_makemake -f is working....thank you @JerzyD.

Answer (score 0):

I have imported Castalia successfully in OMNET++. You can do it as explained here. https://gopalcnepal.wordpress.com/2017/04/12/installing-castalia-in-omnet/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. OP was obviously having problems with OMNeT installation and/or following the "official" installation instructions. Your guide helps someone to use Castalia with the OMNeT GUI.  The official/supported way to use Castalia is via a command line interface.